# SASS not make effect with react page

Tags: reactjs, sass

I created a react app, installed node-sass, and changed the extension to SASS.

After writing some style at sass file, and importing them to the app, I haven't any effects at the page, and I don't know the problem.

Comment: Please share code snippets or more information about your project, the way you currently have your question makes it hard to help you with your problem!

Comment: How can we help you without seeing the code?